# Word for people who like to spend money?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for people who like to purchase lots of things?
For instance, let's say someone has an Iphone 7, but as soon as the Iphone 8 is released, he buys it, even if he doesn't need it at all. In fact, I am looking for a word with a financial perspective, like people who really enjoy spending money.

In my native language, which is Portuguese, we have a specific word for that, which is "consumista", but when I translated it into English, I got "consumerist". However, when I checked this word on Cambridge dictionary, I saw it is mostly used to describe societies, but I am not sure about specific individuals.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a spendthrift

> **spendthrift**  [free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/spendthrift) n. One who spends money recklessly or wastefully. adj. Wasteful or extravagant: spendthrift
>   bureaucrats.

Comment: What about the word "consumerist"? Do you think this word can be used interchangeably with "spendthrift"?

Comment: "consumerist"  is not interchangeable with spendthrift.  I have never heard "consumerist" used to mean an individual.   The closest you could come is "He is a very consumer-oriented person" and that is awkward.

Comment: @ab2 my reading of OP's request was for an english word of such and individual or a few of them, not a society of them

Comment: I agree.  I upvoted your answer, and my comment supported your answer by saying, in response to the OP's comment,  that spendthrift was the correct word and consumerist was not.